# Entity Framework won't save changes to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Database First in my website and i'm trying to update the data of one entry of the database but the changes are not being saved in one part but are working in another one.

This is where i populate the form with the model data or create a new one to reserve the ID:

```
public ActionResult Editar(int ID = 0)
{
    var banner  = new Banner();
    var siteVM  = new SiteViewModel();

    if (ID == 0)
    {
        db.Banner.Add(banner);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        banner = db.Banner.Find(ID);

        siteVM.iePaginas = db.Pagina.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text  = x.nome.ToUpper()
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var pagina in siteVM.iePaginas)
        {
            foreach (var bannerPagina in banner.BannerPagina)
            {
                if (int.Parse(pagina.Value) == bannerPagina.paginaID)
                {
                    pagina.Selected = true;
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    siteVM.Banner = banner;

    return View(siteVM);
}
```

And this is where i save it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Editar(SiteViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var banner = model.Banner;
        banner.rascunho = !banner.ativo;

        if (banner.ID == 0)
        {
            db.Banner.Add(banner);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(banner).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        //Remove the related pages
        foreach (var source in db.BannerPagina.Where(x => x.bannerID == banner.ID))
        {
            db.BannerPagina.Remove(source);
        }

        //Record related pages
        foreach (var pag in model.PaginasSelecionadas)
        {
            db.BannerPagina.Add(new BannerPagina { paginaID = int.Parse(pag.Value), bannerID = banner.ID });
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.Salvo = 1;

        return View(model);
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Error = 1;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The `db.Entry(banner).State = EntityState.Modified;` doesn't work, i get the data in the model and my ModeState is valid but the data isn't changed on the database. Just below that i have:

```
db.BannerPagina.Remove(source); //BannerPagina contains a set of pages that are related to my banner so i can choose the pages i want this banner displayed

db.BannerPagina.Add(new BannerPagina { paginaID = int.Parse(pag.Value), bannerID = banner.ID });
```

And they work fine. I also have tried to use the attach method but it also doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Kind of found my problem, earlier i had changed the `StoreGeneratedPattern` option on my table properties to `Computed` instead of `None` (I did that so i could create an empty object in the database using it's default values), once i changed it back my changes started to be saved in the DB.

Is there a way to make the `Computed` configuration work ?

Comment: Yes, you need to attach the entity and mark it modified before saving changes OR obtain the entity like you did with `source` and update its values. What does that attempt look like? You can also step through with the debugger to capture the SQL query. Then run the query manually to see if that matches what you expect to happen on the database.

Comment: It also doesn't work, the sql is normal.

Comment: What *exactly* did you do with `StoreGeneratedPattern`? Whatever it was, it sounds like an unhealthy hack. Maybe you should revert your question to how to store default values, for which you should be able to find many answers.

Comment: I already search for that and the best option that i could find, beside set the values manually, would be the use of this feature. What i did was change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` value to `Computed` in all the fields of my model in my `edmx` file so it would use the default values instead of null.

Comment: Well, if the properties are marked as `Computed` EF will *never* write their values, only read them after insert/update. If you want the db defaults you have to insert a record with blank values and read it back from the db.

Comment: That's what i thought so after some research, it's a shame that this feature  doesn't let you "update" the Computed fields.